# How do I delete the same line numbers across all files in a directory?

Tags: text-processing, sed, find

I want to delete line 151-154 inclusively from every .fasta file in the directory. I am trying

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i.fix '151,154d' '{}' '+'
```

but it will only run on the first file, not the other 400.

Comment: You probably forgot the `;` (quoted, use `\;` etc.) needed to end the command.

Comment: At least in recent GNU sed, `-i` (`--in-place`) implies `-s` (`--separate`), but I'm not sure that's always the case - maybe that's why it's only applying to the first file?

Comment: This should be done with `ed` or `ex` because `sed -i` is not a true in-place edit.  It writes to a temporary file and then renames it to replace the original file, causing the inode number to change and breaking any hard-links / COW filesystem snapshots, etc.

Comment: What operating system and/or implementation/version of `sed` is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-i` is a non-standard `sed` option. It comes from `perl`. GNU and FreeBSD `sed` added `-i` independently in late 2001, early 2002 to mimic `perl`'s behaviour but with different interfaces. It has made its way into a few more implementations since with more variation (in particular wrt how much of the original file metadata is preserved).

In `perl`, you'd do:

```
perl -ni.back -e 'print unless $. == 151..154' file
```

`$.` is the current line number for the *current input file handle*. When `<>`/`-n` is used, that's the `ARGV` file handle which is open in turn for each of the files passed as argument, but since `ARGV` is not closed in between each file, `$.` is not reset between each file. For that, you'd need:

```
perl -ni.back -e '
  print unless $. == 151..154;
  close ARGV if eof' file1 file2
```

GNU `sed`, the first implementation (AFAIK) to add a `-i` option à la `perl` (added in 2001-09-25 but not released (in 3.95) until one year later), had the line number reset between each file (`-s`, another GNU extension implied).

FreeBSD [did it differently](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base?view=revision&revision=96175). The major differences between GNU and FreeBSD's original API was that `-i` requires an argument in FreeBSD while it's optional in GNU `sed` like in `perl`. And in FreeBSD, initially, the line number was not reset between each file.

In 2007, [FreeBSD aligned with GNU `sed` when it came to the second point](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base?view=revision&revision=168921). The line number was reset between each file and a `-I` option was added to get the old behaviour of `-i`.

`-i` support was added much later to some other `sed` implementations like busybox, NetBSD and OpenBSD but they all aligned with GNU `sed` on both points.

macOS `sed` is based on an old version of FreeBSD's so is probably the only implementation that behaves the old FreeBSD's way nowadays, and probably the one you're using.

So, here, you'd need to either use `perl` with:

```
find . -type f ! -name '*.back' -exec perl -ni.back -ne '
  print unless $. == 151..154;
  close ARGV if eof' {} +
```

Or call one `sed` per file:

```
find . -type f ! -name '*.back' -exec sed -i.back 151,154d {} \;
```

Or install and use GNU `sed` or GNU `awk` (with `-i /usr/share/awk/inplace.awk`¹ and match on `FNR`, not `NR`) or [`ed`/`ex` based approaches](/a/428021).

---

<sup>¹ **do not use `-i inplace`** as `gawk` tries to load the `inplace` extension (as `inplace` or `inplace.awk`) from the current working directory first, where someone could have planted malware. The path of the `inplace` extension supplied with `gawk` may vary with the system, see the output of `gawk 'BEGIN{print ENVIRON["AWKPATH"]}'`</sup>

Comment: I think you meant to type `\;` rather than `+` for the one-sed-per-file version.   Also `perl` has the `File::Find` module which allows recursive file-finding like `find` inside the perl script itself.

Comment: @cas, thanks. Fixed now. About `File::Find`, yes, though it doesn't do as safe a directory traversal as `find`, and it would make the code more complicated. [That code is still unsafe because of `perl`'s `<>`, only partly alleviated by the `-T` here](/q/170013).

Comment: I've been reading up on the `<>` and `-p`/`-n` issue again, and I'm still appalled that p5 devs chose to keep the unsafe behaviour as default rather than adding a use feature or cmd-line option to enable it for the extremely rare instances where someone might want magic open on <>.  There isn't even a switch or pragma or anything to disable it for those who want to write `-p`/`-n` one-liners that are safe for any @ARGV.

Comment: @cas Actually,my bad. It's safe here because of the `-i`

Answer (score 2):

This answer uses `ex` rather than `sed -i` because `sed -i` isn't a true in-place edit.  It writes to a temporary file and then renames it to replace the original, which causes the inode number to change.  This breaks any hard links and snapshots on COW filesystems (like btrfs or zfs) and anything else dependent on a file's inode number.  The same is true of most other common commands that implement a `-i` / `--in-place` option (including `perl`'s `-i` option).

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'for f in "$@" ; do
    cp -a "$f" "$f.fix"
    printf "%s\n" 151,154d x | ex -s -- "$f" 
  done' sh {} +
```

This forks `sh` to process the list of files found by `find`.

The `sh` process first makes a backup copy of the original file (using GNU `cp`'s `-a` option to preserve all attributes like timestamp and permissions), then it invokes `ex`  to edit the file.

The `printf ... | ex ...` above pipes two `ex` commands **(*)** into `ex`, each command separated by a newline.  The first command deletes lines 151-154.  The second (`x`) tells `ex` to write the changes to the file (by default, `ex` will quit without saving unless you tell it to save).  If no changes were made, then `x` quits without saving, same as the `:x` command in `vi`.

Note: if any individual input file has less than 154 lines, then **no** changes will be made to that file.

The `-s` option to `ex` tells it to be silent, and not print any diagnostic messages.

The `--` prevents any filename arguments from being interpreted as options by `ex` (in case any of the filenames start with a `-`).  This is not strictly necessary here because all filenames output by the `find` command here will have `./` pre-pended - but it is harmless and a good habit to acquire when processing unknown filenames.

**(*)** `ex` commands are pretty much the same as `sed` commands.  Originally, a long time ago, `ed` was the file editor and `sed` was the stream editor based on `ed`.  Later, `vi` was written as a visual version of `ed`.  `vi` added a visual editing mode but retained the `ed` commands in its `:` command mode.  `vi` can also be run as `ex` for command-mode editing without the visual mode, which is what is being used here.  `ex` is still mostly a clone of `ed` but has gained a few minor improvements (like the `x` command) over the original `ed` in the decades since it was first written.